# How to "reset" concatMap in rxjs?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Im attempting to call a function that dispatches an action that in turn triggers an effect that calls a service as many times as there are pages, starting from page 1. The issue that im having is that, after I call the function, it triggers as many times as I need, but the "pageIndex" isnt resetting back to 0.

```
    this.store.dispatch(fromStore.getAllUsersByFilters({ filters: this.searchFilters.value, pageIndex: 0 }));
```

Inside the effect:

```
 @Effect()
    // other stuff
    concatMap(([{ filters }, groupNumbers], pageIndex) =>
      this.userService.getUsersByFilters(filters, groupNumbers, pageIndex).pipe(
        map((res: UserSearchResponse) => {
          if (res.success) {
            if(pageIndex < res.totalResults / res.pageSize){
              this.store.dispatch(userActions.getAllUsersByFilters({filters: filters, pageIndex: res.pageIndex++}));
            }
            return userActions.getAllUsersSuccess({ users: res.results });
          }
          this.message.showErrorMessage('Failed to Retrieve Enrollments')
          return userActions.getAllUsersFailure();
        })
      )
    )
  )
```

When I run the search again, It doesnt start from 0 again, but instead from the next number after pageIndex. I dont understand why this is happening, as I was under the impression that if im passing a '0' into the dispatch function, it would start over. I'm aware that concatMap returns all the values from each subscription but I cant find a way to reset it without touching the state (if that would even work at this point). I'd appreciate any help on this issue.

If anyone can even propose another a better way to go about doing this i would like to hear that also

Comment: when you reach a second time the `effect` for type `getAllUsersByFilters`, `pageIndex` is not 0 even though you are dispatching it with 0? that's the issue?